# Classification model bench mark accuracy

Tags: r, classification, benchmarking, stat

I have a task where I need to create a benchmark model of my  training dataset. I need help with the coding to understand how I would approach this task. The 5 classification models are KNN, Kernal SVM, Decision Tree, Logistic Regression and k-nearest Neighbour.

Any example with good explanation will help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the comparison model is, however with the `caret` package it is easy to create many different models, do parameters tuning with cross-validation, and compare the results. Just for information KNN and k-nearest Neighbour are the same thing.
In the example below I compare the models just in terms of accuracy, not speed.
I use a built-in dataset available in the `caret` package which has a binary outcome (column `Class` in the example, with values `Good` and `Bad`).
The process is the following:

**data loading and splitting**

```
library(caret)

data("GermanCredit")
str(GermanCredit[,1:10])
index <- createDataPartition(GermanCredit$Class,p=0.7,list=F)
training <- GermanCredit[index,1:10]
test <- GermanCredit[-index,1:10]
```

**set the resampling method: 10-fold cross-validation repeated 5 times**

```
# run multiple algorithms once, with 5 repeated 10 fold cv
trainControl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", 
                             number=10, 
                             repeats=5,
                             savePrediction="final"
)
```

**tuning the models and compare resampling statistics**

here is the list of [all models available in caret](https://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html)
Since you do not specify which decision tree algorithm or what kind of kernel do you want I choose C5.0 as a decision tree and an SVM with Radial Basis Function Kernel.

```
#list of model to tune
algorithmList <- c('rpart', 'knn', 'glm','svmRadial')

#model tuning
set.seed(5)
models <- lapply(algorithmList,function(x){
  train(
    Class ~ .,
    data = training,
    method = x,
    trControl = trainControl
  )
})
```

**resampled statistics from cross-validation**

```
results <- resamples(models)#results from cv
summary(results)
bwplot(results)
```

**test the accuracy of models on the test set**

```
predicted <-
  list(
    c5.0 = predict(models[[1]], test[,-10]),
    knn = predict(models[[2]], test[,-10]),
    glm = predict(models[[3]], test[,-10]),
    svm = predict(models[[4]], test[,-10])
  )

cm <- lapply(predicted,confusionMatrix,reference=test$Class,positive="Good")
acc <- lapply(cm,function(x){
  o <- x$overall[1:2]
  b <- x$byClass[5:7]
  df <- c(o,b)
})
df <- round(do.call(rbind,acc),3)
```

The `df` object look like this:

```
    > df
     Accuracy Kappa Precision Recall    F1
c5.0    0.697 0.019     0.703  0.981 0.819
knn     0.660 0.008     0.701  0.895 0.787
glm     0.717 0.143     0.726  0.957 0.825
svm     0.723 0.157     0.728  0.967 0.830
```

Look [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/measuring-performance.html#measures-for-predicted-classes) to see how the function `confusionMatrix` calculate these statistics.